# Creating multiple output files from a gulp task

Tags: gulp

I'm learning the gulp way of doing things after using grunt exclusively in the past.  I'm struggling to understand how to pass multiple inputs to get multiple outputs w/gulp.

Let's say I have a large project that has specialized js on a per page basis:

**The Grunt Way:**

```
grunt.initConfig({
  uglify: {
    my_target: {
      files: {
        'dest/everypage.min.js': ['src/jquery.js', 'src/navigation.js'],
        'dest/special-page.min.js': ['src/vendor/handlebars.js', 'src/something-else.js']
      }
    }
  }
});
```

This may be a poor example as it violates the "do only one thing" principle since `grunt-uglify` is concatenating and uglifying.  In any event I'm interested in learning how to accomplish the same thing using gulp.

Comment: The [gulp-uglify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uglify) documentation shows this in action it just doesn't provide the concatenation of the files. Basically you feed in a glob as as the `src`, `uglify()` them, and then tell gulp the `dest` you want the uglified files to be stored.  After, this is done, run a separate task that reads in as the src, the list of files you want to concatenate, and the `dest` you want for the file.

Comment: Here is a plugin you can use to concat files with gulp: [gulp-concat](https://github.com/contra/gulp-concat)

Comment: I understand now that gulp separates the `concat` and `uglify` processing, which makes sense.  My question is how can I tell gulp that I want to combine `['file1.js', 'file2.js', 'file3.js']` into `dist/everypage.js` **AND** `['file4.js', 'file5.js']` into `'dist/special.js'`?

Comment: Sounds like you need to create two separate streams, both containing the uglify and concat calls, one stream to generate everypage.js and another to generate special.js. And if you need to return the combined stream, you could try using something like [merge-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/merge-stream), here is an [example](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/using-multiple-sources-in-one-task.md) of merge-stream in action.

Comment: Is there a manageable way to maintain a list of the sources and their concatenated destination in a format like json and pass them into a task rather than creating a single task with ~20 streams that winds up being a hundred lines?

Comment: Absolutely! I use that type of a setup for my build automation to keep it simple and clean.  here is an [example](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/using-external-config-file.md) I found that shows how you can set something like that up. You are free to setup your JSON structure how you see fit.

Comment: A-hah! That's the mindset I was missing -- code your Gulpfile like any other JS and run the same concat task as a function.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to @AnilNatha I'm starting to think with more of a Gulp mindset.

For my case I have a load of files that need to be concatenated.  I offloaded these to a config object that my concat task iterates over:

```
// Could be moved to another file and `required` in.
var files = { 
  'polyfills.js': ['js/vendor/picturefill.js', 'js/vendor/augment.js'],
  'map.js': [
    'js/vendor/leaflet.js',
    'js/vendor/leaflet.markercluster.min.js',
    'js/vendor/jquery.easyModal.js',
    'js/vendor/jquery-autocomplete.min.js',
    'js/vendor/underscore.1.8.3.js',
    'js/map.js'
  ],
  ...
};
var output = './build/js';

// Using underscore.js pass the key/value pair to custom concat function
gulp.task('concat', function (done) {
  _.each(files, concat);
  // bs.reload(); if you're using browsersync
  done(); // tell gulp this asynchronous process is complete

});

// Custom concat function
function concat(files, dest) {
  return gulp.src(files)
    .pipe($.concat(dest))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(output));
}
```

Comment: I don't know who keeps downvoting you, but good to see that you're making progress. One suggestion, be careful when creating gulp tasks that don't return anything because it can cause problems if you later use these tasks as dependencies for other tasks. This is why I had mentioned the use of merge-stream to return combined streams since you needed to call your concat function multiple times.

Comment: I used the callback technique that I think covers your comment, thanks again @AnilNatha

Comment: For those still wondering, gulpjs.org has a nice recipe for this: http://gulpjs.org/recipes/running-task-steps-per-folder.html